# ¿Acceso denegado al ejecutar programa compilado en C?

Tags: c, linux, centos7

Tengo un programa `test_fork.c` en el cual hago un llamado a la función fork() para crear un nuevo proceso y gestionar el resultado de intentar crear un nuevo proceso, entonces, el código es compilado correctamente, pero al ejecutarlo me aparece:

> Permiso denegado

Aquí el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1){
                printf("Error al crear el proceso hijo\n");
                exit(0);
        }

        if(pid){
                printf("Proceso padre, el PID de mi hijo es %d\n");
        }else{
                printf("Soy el hijo, ejecutando herramienta date\n");
                execve("bin/date", NULL, NULL);
        }
}
```

Adjunto imagen en consola de ejecución del programa con `./test_fork.c`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Agregué permiso de ejecución al fichero con el siguiente comando:

```
chmod 755 test_fork.c
```

Comment: ¿Estás tratando de compilar, o de ejecutar tu programa?

Comment: Ejecutar, ya noté el error. Ahora estoy probando ejecutar con ./nombre_fichero.c pero me dice acceso denegado, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Actualicé toda la información para que la pregunta sea sobre el acceso denegado al intentar ejecutar el fichero.

Comment: Estás intentando ejecutar el código fuente. C es un lenguaje compilado, tienes que convertirlo primero en código máquina con `gcc -o test_fork test_fork.c`, para crear el ejecutable `test_fork` que ya podrás ejecutar (si la compilación no encuentra errores)

Answer (score -1):

No se ejecuta por dos razones,

La primera es que ese archivo que no posee permisos de ejecución, en linux, si quieres que un archivo se ejecute, debe tener estos permisos, acá en linux no existe cosas como `.exe`, existen son archivos con permisos de ejecución, lo que más se le parece a los `.exe` son los archivos binarios y aún así tienen muy poco o nada en común.

Lo segundo y el cual es realmente el problema, es que es un archivo que es imposible su ejecución, un archivo puede tener permisos de ejecución, pero si no posee una estructura que ejecutar, no lo hará, un ejemplo, trata de ejecutar un archivo plano donde solo está tu nombre, es ridículo, pasa lo mismo con esto, estas tratando de ejecutar un archivo `.c` donde solo está el código fuente de tu programa, debes primero compilarlo y ejecutar el binario.